# Uncaught InvalidStateError in JSON.stringify

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, stringify

I've read this other thread and it was no good: [Put data into JSON with Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18369280/put-data-into-json-with-jquery)

Whenever I try to JSON.stringify an object array I get an error saying:

```
Uncaught InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable.
```

Here is my JS:

```
            var responseItems = [];

            var keynoteContainer = $('div.keynote-questions');
            var eventQuestionContainer = $('div.event-questions');
            var sessionContainer = $('div.session-questions');
            var eventId = $('#Evaluation-Event-Id').val();

            keynoteContainer.children().each(function (index, el) {
                var element = $(el);

                var id = "-1";
                var parentId = element.find('input[type=hidden]').val();
                var parentType = "Keynote";
                var responseValue = element.find('.response-item-slider').slider("option", "value");
                var responseText = "";

                var response = { "Id": id, "EventId": eventId, "ParentId": parentId, "ParentType": parentType, "ResponseValue": responseValue, "ResponseText": responseText };
                responseItems.push(response);
            });                    

            eventQuestionContainer.children().each(function (index, el) {
                var element = $(el);

                var id = "-1";
                var parentId = element.find('input[type=hidden]').val();
                var parentType = "EventQuestion";
                var responseValue = element.find('.response-item-slider').slider("option", "value");
                var responseText = element.find('textarea').val();

                var response = { "Id": id, "EventId": eventId, "ParentId": parentId, "ParentType": parentType, "ResponseValue": responseValue, "ResponseText": responseText };
                responseItems.push(response);
            });

            sessionContainer.children().each(function (index, el) {
                var element = $(el);

                var id = "-1";
                var parentId = element.find('input[type=hidden]').val();
                var parentType = "Session";
                var responseValue = element.find('.response-item-slider').slider("option", "value");
                var responseText = "";

                var response = { "Id": id, "EventId": eventId, "ParentId": parentId, "ParentType": parentType, "ResponseValue": responseValue, "ResponseText": responseText };
                responseItems.push(response);
            });

            responseItems = JSON.stringify(responseItems);
```

I've tried to log everything and it only breaks at the last line where I stringify it.

How can I fix this? Any piece of advise or information would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What browser is giving you this error?

Comment: Sounds like a cross-frame reference that got garbage-collected. Are you using anything such?

Comment: @Bergi huh? I don't think that's my post.

Comment: @Bergi Hmm... you may be on to something there. I've got a page which loads a partial view (evaluation items) into a DIV. I then go through each item in that div to build the responseItems object array. it works fine (logged everything) up until the stringify where I get that error.

Comment: @AnimaSola is the "partial view" in an `<iframe>`?  Since each `<iframe>` is a distinct JavaScript global environment, when objects are handed between frames then odd things can happen.

Comment: @Pointy nope. It's loaded onto a div via $('divname').html(viewdata). viewdata is html returned from a controller action.

Comment: Who added the "may already have an answer" post? I mentioned on my first line that it was no good!

Comment: @AnimaSola Just try removing properties one by one until serialization works. You should quickly find the issue.

Comment: @plalx could it be one of the properties being undefined? because I've got a scenario where it could be either a textvalue or slidervalue and I just put both. when the object is added/made, the property has a value of undefined. I just imagined it would turn into null once serialized. could this be the problem?

Comment: @AnimaSola, I dont think so. `undefined` values are ignored. Try this code to find the erroneous property. It will go through the array, remove one property at a time and try to stringify: `Object.keys(responseItems[0]).forEach(function (key, index) {
    var error = false;

    responseItems.forEach(function (item) {
        delete item[key];
    });

    try { 
        JSON.stringify(responseItems);
    } catch (e) {
        error = true;
    }

    if (!error) {
         throw 'erroneous property: ' + key;
    }
});`

Comment: I got it working, it was definitely the undefined property that fixed it. Defined both as empty strings first rather than a value from an element.

Comment: @AnimaSola, That's wierd, I still doubt it's because of undefined values. `JSON.stringify({test: undefined});` works well for me.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error.  In my case, I had forgotten the .val() when I was setting one of the model properties.  There wasn't an error until I tried to JSON.stringify the model

```
        this.model.set(
        {
            customername: this.$("#customername").val(),
            jobtitle: this.$("#jobtitle"),  //This was the line causing the error
            testimonialtext: this.$("#testimonialtext").val()
        });
```

Comment: Had the same issue. I had set `$tr.find($('.asm-note').val())` to a property in the object, when what I actually meant was `$tr.find('.asm-note').val()`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. In my case it was fixed casting my trouble variable toArray(). I mean something like this:
   `responseItems = responseItems.toArray();`
I don't know why that variable looks like an Array but it isn't
after that you can call:
    `JSON.stringfy(responseItems);`
without problems.

PD: sorry for my english I'm not native english speaker